# Enconding columns in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, encoding, utf-8

I have some columns of text that are like the example below. I already tried using `.decode` for UTF-8 and it didn't work. I tried to use `chardet` to confirm whether the column is UTF-8 and confirmed that it was. But nothing so far has converted the texts. Do you know any way to solve it? I'll leave my codes below too.

Exemple of text in column:

```
SECRETARIA DE FINANÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂAS
RECURSOS ORDINÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂRIOS
IMPOSTOS, TAXAS E CONTRIBUIÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ...
INDENIZAÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂES
```

My codes:

Detect Encode

```
import chardet

column= 'orgao_nome'

def detect_encoding(cell):
    result = chardet.detect(cell.encode())
    return result['encoding']

df['detect_encoding'] = df[column].apply(detect_encoding)
```

Decode

```
column= 'orgao_nome'

target_encoding = 'utf-8'

df[column] = df[column].str.encode(target_encoding, errors='ignore').str.decode(target_encoding)
```

Comment: Python strings are already Unicode so there's nothing to decode. The data was loaded using the wrong encoding. How was that done? That's where you need to set the *correct* encoding.

Comment: `ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂAS` looks suspiciously like UTF8 bytes that were decoded using Latin1 instead of UTF8. Characters outside the US-ASCII range are encoded using two bytes. The first byte becomes `Ã` if the bytes are decoded as Latin1. How was that data loaded? That's where the error needs to be fixed

Comment: i'm using  pd.read_csv('recife-dados-receitas-2021.csv', sep=';',encoding = 'utf8')

Comment: I realized that the source file already comes this way

Comment: That means whatever produced the text used the wrong codepage *twice* - one that converted UTF8 to Latin1 characters, producing `ÃÂ` and the mangled text was stored *as* UTF8, resulting in 2 bytes for each of the characters.

Comment: Is there anything I can do or just generating the file correctly?

Comment: You'll have to inspect the file generation process. Something's really weird here. `SECRETARIA DE FINANZAS` uses just ASCII characters so where did `ÃÂÃÂÃÂÃÂ` come from? That's 8 identical bytes `ÃÂ ÃÂ ÃÂ ÃÂ` instead of a single Z. What was that line supposed to show? I suspect the characters were lost before the final file was generated